# how to filter out a pattern in python regular expressions, till the input word

Tags: python, regex

In python, i want to extract a particular sub string till the input word provided.

Consider the following string:-

```
"Name: abc and Age:24"
```

I want to extract the string `"Name : abc and"` änd `"Age:24"`seperately.
I am currently using the following pattern:

```
re.search(r'%S+\s*:[\S\s]+',pattern).
```

but o/p is the whole string.

Comment: Do you need `and`? Because you could split on `and` and get [this](http://ideone.com/tP9Xwv).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` :

```
>>> import re
>>> s="Name: abc and Age:24"
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+:[a-z\s]+|[A-Za-z]+:\d+',s)
['Name: abc and ', 'Age:24']
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/blR6iDgixOCsItbu)

In preceding pattern as in your string the keys(`Age` and `Name`) starts with uppercase letters you ca use `[A-Za-z]+` for match them.that will match any combinations of uppercase and lowercase letters with len 1 or more, but for the rest of string after `:` you can just use lower case letters, and also the same for second part.but for string after `:` in second part you just match a digit with length 1 or more!

If its possible that you had string in second part after `:` you can use `\w` instead of `\d` :

```
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+:[a-z\s]+|[A-Za-z]+:\w+',s)
['Name: abc def ghi ', 'Location:Earth']
```

Comment: if the string is "Name: abc def ghi Location:Earth", then what could be the pattern?

Comment: @NandaKishoreCh if its possible that you have string in second part you need to use `\w` instead `\d`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `re.findall`.

```
>>> s = "Name: abc and Age:24"
>>> re.findall(r'\S+\s*:.*?(?=\s*\S+\s*:|$)', s)
['Name: abc and', 'Age:24']
>>> re.findall(r'[^\s:]+\s*:.*?(?=\s*[^\s:]+\s*:|$)', s)
['Name: abc and', 'Age:24']
```

- `[^\s:]+` matches any character but not of `:` or space one or more times. So this matches the key part.
- `\s*:` matches zero or more spaces and the colon symbol.
- `.*?` matches zero or more non-greedily until
- `(?=\s*[^\s:]+\s*:|$)` the key part  or end of the line. `(?=...)` called positive lookahead which asserts whether a match is possible or not. It won't match any single character.

**OR**

You could use `re.split`.

```
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?=[^\s:]+\s*:)', s)
['Name: abc and', 'Age:24']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/32)

Comment: could you please explain what this  means?
.*?(?=\s*\S+\s*:|$)

Comment: In general ^ means from the begining if the string right?

Comment: [^\s:]+ should mean one or more of the spaces or ':' character from the begining right?

Comment: any character but not of space or colon, one or more times. Match occurs anywhere in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex:

```
\w+[:]\w+|\w+[:](\s)\w+|\w+(\s)[:]\w+
```

Here's a breakdown:

```
\w+[:]\w+
```

\w means get a word, [:] means get a colon character, the + symbol says get a word which is before the colon character. The rest of it works the other way around :)

The | symbol is just an OR operator which I use to check if spaces follow or come before the colon.

It will get the words that are before and after a colon. It works when there is a space before or after the colon as well.